# Table - How to skip displaying data in column1, while column2 has more than one line to display

Tags: javascript, html, css-tables

How to skip displaying data in ItemA, while ItemB has more than one line to display:

ItemA = [Color Fruit, Nuts]

ItemB = [[green], [orange, apple, grapes], [cashew, almond]]

```
             if (this.point.customTT === 'Item') {
                    let tableBody = '';
                    itemA.forEach((name1, i) => {
                    itemB[i].forEach((name2, j) => {

                      tableBody += `
                          <tr>
                            <td >${itemA[i]}</td>
                            <td >${itemB[i][j]}</td>
                          </tr>
                     `

                   })
                   })

                   const html = `
                      <table>
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>ItemA</th>
                          <th>ItemB</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>               
                      ${tableBody}
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
                 `
                 return html;
            }
```

Right now, above code returns table as below ->  you can notice, fruit and nuts are written many a times

```
ItemA   ItemB

Color   Green
Fruit   Orange
Fruit   Apple
Fruit   Grapes
Nuts
```

Like to display table as below -  not repeat itemA

```
ItemA   ItemB

Color   Green
Fruit   Orange
        Apple
        Grapes
Nuts
```

Comment: add a condition where you display ```itemA[i]``` only if ```j===0``` ? Like :   <td>${j===0?itemA[i]:null}</td>?

Comment: That worked as expected. You can pls add this as answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have a minor problem, lets assume 'Nuts' do not have 'itemB' value (as edited above). Now,  j===0  does not work in this scenario. Because Nuts do not have even a single value to check that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added an extra if statement to handle the case where itemA is longer than itemB :

```js
const ItemA = ["Color", "Fruit", "Nuts"];
//const ItemB = [["green"], ["orange", "apple", "grapes"], ["cashew", "almond"]];
const ItemB = [["green"], ["orange", "apple", "grapes"]];

let tableBody = "";
ItemA.forEach((name1, i) => {
  if (ItemB[i]) {
    ItemB[i].forEach((name2, j) => {
      tableBody += `
        <tr>
          <td >${j === 0 ? name1 : ""}</td>
          <td >${name2}</td>
        </tr>
   `;
    });
  } else {
    tableBody += `
  <tr>
    <td >${name1}</td>
    <td ></td>
  </tr>
`;
  }
});

const html = `
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ItemA</th>
        <th>ItemB</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>               
    ${tableBody}
    </tbody>
</table>
`;
console.log(html);
```

Comment: I have exactly figured the same way for fixing. Except I have used - if (itemB][i].length > 0) {}. Yours seems much more neater. Thank you for the answer.